# why is my expectation of where the critical points are disagreeing with my graph?

Tags: differential-geometry, gradient-flows

given the parametrised function

$$f_t(x,y,z)=z^3+tz-x^2+y^2$$

We know that that the gradient vector field is

$\nabla f_t=(-2x,2y,3z^2+t)$

Now I originally thought that the critical points were at $(0,0,\sqrt{\tfrac{-t}{3}})$. but when I graphed the level sets of the functions for t=0,1,-1. It seemed as though critical points happened at $(0,0,0), (0,0,\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{3}})(0,0,-\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{3}})$

where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Can you draw the level graph for complex values?

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$t=1 \implies 3z^2+t >0 \quad \forall z$$

therefore we can't have a critical point for that value of the parameter $t$, more in general we need $t \le 0$ as a necessary condition to have critical points.

Comment: This is what I had thought originally but drawing the level sets ( on the xz plane ) gave me an image for t=1 which looked identical to t=-1 except that one was shifted above the x-axis and one was shiftedbelow . but one of these is supposed to have a critical point and the other is not ? what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: also critical points also occur when the derivative is undefined so z=\sqrt{\tfrac{-t}{3}} for t>0 , would constitute and undefined point in $\Bbb R^3$ so would be a critical point no ?

Comment: The function $f_t$ is differentiable at all $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$. By definition, a critical point is where the derivative is zero.